# PHP variable mysteriously changing from integer to string

Tags: php, exception

I am trying to implement a catch-all exception handler in PHP such that it will set the status code of the response to the status contained in the exception (if present), but for some reason when I pass what is definitely an integer (because I am logging `gettype()`) into a function, it is somehow turning into a `string` on the way to that function because if I log its type immediately in the function it is now a `string`!

Clearly I don't know enough about PHP because this is confounding the heck out of me. Why on earth would this ever happen and how do I stop it from happening?

```
function qpGlobalExceptionHandler($e) {
    $code = intval($e->getCode());
    error_log("Global exception (".$code." ".gettype($code)."): ".$e->getMessage());

    $this->sendReply($code, $e->getMessage(), false);
}
```

At this point in the error log I see:

> Global exception (404 integer): CouchDB Error: not_found (deleted) …

But inside `sendReply`, which looks like this:

```
public function sendReply($responseCode,$responseText=false,$allowCaching=true) {
    error_log("In sendReply. gettype(responseCode): ".gettype($responseCode));

    // ...
}
```

In the error log I get:

> In sendReply. gettype(responseCode): string

Now I know PHP can be weird, but *what the heck*?

**Update:** So I realized one problem, and that was that I was referencing `$this` from the global exception handler, which is not a member of any class. Strangely the call *somehow* still ended up making its way to the actual member function I wanted to call, but I'm guessing there must be some strange fallback logic PHP was doing to find the "best match" for the function call and in that logic the parameters ended up getting converted to strings somehow.

Anyhow I have ended up just taking a different approach and it's no longer a problem. I still have no idea what was going on though, so if there are any PHP pros out there who can enlighten me I'd still be happy to learn.

Comment: what version of php?

Comment: PHP 5.6.28.....

Comment: can you print stack trace if type of responsecode is string?

Comment: Using the given code, and passing in `new Exception("Test", 99);`, I receive the expected output: integer, integer. `PHP 5.6.30`

Comment: @Lashane Strangely, `debug_backtrace()` doesn't seem to generate anything.

Comment: strange, how do you use it? also - probably add value of responseCode to 2nd output

Comment: @Lashane Perhaps it had no stack trace because it was inside the global exception handler? Anyway please see my update; I've worked around it for now.

Comment: @devios1 can you rollback your changes and output `responseCode` value in `sendReply`, I suppose it will be exception message (not code)

Comment: @Lashane You're onto something. It is a completely different result: "HTTP/1.0 202 Accepted". That actually gives me a clue. I will need to debug it more. But not today. Thanks for the help.